# Buying International Stock

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, markets

I bought a Canadian stock on the US OTC market.

What I'm trying to understand is does the stock get impacted by the US or Canadian market.

For example, if the Dow, S&P 500, NASDAQ are all down does that necessarily mean the Canadian stock will get negatively impacted?  Or is it primarily impacted by the Canadian market?

I understand that it's a global market, but I'm just wondering on a day by day basis.

Comment: Which stock are you asking about?

Comment: Canadian stock is: TWMJF

Answer (score 1):

I quickly put the data in Excel and the correlations of daily returns are as follows:

TWMJF vs. SPY (S&P500) = 0.145

TWMJF vs. EWC (iShares Canada) = 0.188

SPY vs. EWC = 0.710

Data from April 2014 (start of TWMJF data) to now, Yahoo Finance, adjusted close.

This would suggest that the stock moves quite independently from either the US and Canada market (both the ETFs focus on large caps, which this stock is not). It is slightly more correlated with Canada, but I wouldn't consider the difference significant.

I would add that individual stocks are often more driven by their sector events (even international ones) rather than country events, especially if the countries are as similar as US vs. Canada.

Comment: Since the time I posted this question, I haven't noticed a correlation with the US market.  I haven't really looked at the correlation with the CSE and TWMJF, which you already have.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if the Dow, S&P 500, NASDAQ are all down does that necessarily mean the Canadian stock will get negatively impacted? Or is it primarily impacted by the Canadian market?

The `TWMJF` stock makes up a very small part of the Canadian market so it affects the overall market, but this doesn't mean that the overall market affects this stock.

So then the answer is: **no, the `TWMJF` stock price will not necessarily follow either US or Canadian market indexes**.

However, there can be major **events** which can affect the markets, including the stocks which make up the markets. `TWMJF` will probably be more sensitive to Canadian events than US events.

Comment: So it really depends on the stock?

Comment: Yes. An American company's stock will respond differently to events than a Canadian one's will